# Comparing two lists adding strikethrough

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to write a macros to automate comparing two list in excel. If I a number in a first list does not appear in the second list, it will be striked through. But I had trouble with the VLookup function. ActiveCell is the start of data. i is first row index (i.e A6), j is the first column index (i.e A). m is send column index (i.e B), n is second row index (i.e B6). h is the length of first column and k is the length of second column.

I want to keep everything in generic term like (i,j,m,n) because I don't know how big my data is.

```
Sub test1()
Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim h As Long, k As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim m As Long, n As Long
    
    i = ActiveCell.Row
    j = ActiveCell.Column
    m = j + 1
    n = i
    
    h = ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row
    k = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    
    Do While i <= h
         If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, j), sh.Range(Cells(n, m), Cells(k, m)), 1, False)) = False Then
            Cells(i, j).Font.Strikethrough = True
        End If
    i = i + 1
    Loop

    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: If you are using VBA you don't need to use Vlookup formulas.  Just loop through each column's cell and compare values to the next column's cells ... Like comparing two arrays ...

Comment: Loop through 1st range of cells using `For Each` loop and use `Range().Find()` on the 2nd range to compare values.

Answer (score 0):

### Missing Numbers

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub StrikeThroughMissingNumbers()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sfCellAddress As String = "B2" ' read
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dfCellAddress As String = "A2" ' write
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sfCellAddress)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = RefColumn(sfCell)
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dfCellAddress)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = RefColumn(dfCell)
    If drg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    Dim ddrg As Range
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim dValue As Variant
    Dim dDont As Boolean
    
    For Each dCell In drg.Cells
        dValue = dCell.Value
        If IsNumeric(dValue) Then ' is a number
            If IsNumeric(Application.Match(dValue, srg, 0)) Then ' is a match
                dDont = True
            'Else ' is not a match
            End If
        'Else ' is not a number
        End If
        If dDont Then ' don't combine
            dDont = False
        Else ' combine
            Set ddrg = RefCombinedRange(ddrg, dCell)
        End If
    Next dCell
                
    If ddrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no match
    
    ddrg.Font.Strikethrough = True ' in one go

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the one-column range from the first cell
'               of a range ('FirstCell') to the bottom-most non-empty cell
'               of the first cell's worksheet column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    Const ProcName As String = "RefColumn"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to a range combined from two ranges.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefCombinedRange( _
    ByVal CombinedRange As Range, _
    ByVal AddRange As Range) _
As Range
    If CombinedRange Is Nothing Then
        Set RefCombinedRange = AddRange
    Else
        Set RefCombinedRange = Union(CombinedRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Function
```